# Partial view with ajax and jQuery UI.Dialog

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using a standard MVC4 EF5 setup and have a standard view which loads data from the db onto a table.

At the start of the table I have a column for each record with an Add button. The functionality I want is to click the button, popup a model dialog box with a form and add something to the item in the grid that was clicked (a 1 to many).

Lets say I have a list of vans available shown in the list. And when I click the add button beside the particular van where I want to add a passenger, I want a popup to show that allows me to type the details of the passenger so they can be assigned to that van.

I think I am over complicating this. But my brain is fried. I tried partial views with ajax. I tried jQuery UI.Dialog. Im just lost. I am trying to figure out how to find the id of the record I clicked (given the buttons are all generated by a for each loop in the view as normal and numbering them 1 to X does not tell me the id of the record I clicked). So even if I get the popup showing, I wont know which van to assign the passenger to.

If your woundering where the passenger list is coming from, its another table. And effectively any passenger can be assigned to any van. Its hypothetical.

Im actually working on a document generator and so there is a many to many relationship between document parts and documents (a given document part, can appear or belong to many documents, and a document can contain many document parts). I know its messy, this is why I did not want to use the real example.

I'm thinking its maybe an easy enough problem to solve but I have been at it since Friday and the brain left home!

Edit: Adding Code:

Here is the main view: The main problem I am having with this is the way the grid is constructed. I think its partially razor, partially html, partially html helper, and partially javascript. I don't know which part is which, but I just need to get a popup to show for each button in the table, and to have an id I can assign values to. I cant figure out how to do it here.

```
Html.Grid(dbaccess().Where(c => something = something
                    ).Select(o => new
                        {
                            Name = o.Name,
                            Comment = o.Comment,
                            Status = o.Status,
                        }

                    , "grdConfiguration", 0, htmlRowClass: (p) => (row++ % 2 != 0) ? "" : "oddRow"
                    , columns: new[]{ 


//THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE BELOW .... It shows a button in the table, but...
//how do I make it unique. Is it even necessary to do so.
// How do I get the ID of the record at this location when this button is pressed.

//This is the code as originally posted: For context
new Helpers.GridColumn(value: (a) => "<input type=\"button\" class=\"btn\" id=\"BtnHello\" value=\"Add\" />"),

//for some reason when I try the following alternative as suggest by the answers so far - it doesn't work.
new Helpers.GridColumn(value: (a) => "<input type=\"button\" class=\"btn\" data-ThisId=\"@model.SomeId\" value=\"Add\" />"),


//THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE ABOVE....

     there is more columns but this button calls the jQuery...
```

On this view I also have some Div tags in which to load the partial... I can actually get this to popup. But that's about all I can do. And only when I click the first button in the table.

```
<div id='SomePopUp' style='display: none;'>
    //@using (Html.BeginForm())
    //{
    //    <div>
    //        <span class="display-label">Quantity: </span>
    //        <span class="display-field"><input type="text" id="txtQuantity" /></span>
    //    </div>
    //    <div>
    //        <span class="display-label">Comments: </span>
    //        <span class="display-field"><textarea rows="7"></textarea></span>
    //    </div>
    //}
</div>
```

I also have a script section on this view with the code for the popup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#BtnHello").click(function ()
    {
        $("#SomePopUp").dialog(
            {
                resizable: false,
                height: 400,
                width: 400,
                modal: true,
                title:"add to {Some ID}:", //I want the id to show here so I know I have the record I want.
                buttons:
                    {
                        Submit : function ()
                        {
                            $(this).dialog('Some Text');
                        },
                        Cancel: function ()
                        {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
            });
    });
</script>
```

I have a controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddExtra(int id)
    {
        //Fairly sure I should be doing something with this id, but how do I get it from the button.

        return PartialView();
    }
```

And for the partial view I have

```
@model CM.ViewModels.AddExtraPackagesViewModel

<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Add Something</h3>
</div>
<div>
 //I was using ajax here...
@*@using (Ajax.BeginForm("DoSomething", "Something", FormMethod.Post,
                new AjaxOptions
                {
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    HttpMethod = "POST",
                    UpdateTargetId = "list-of-something"
                }))
{
    <div class="modal-body">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Quantity);
        @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Comment);
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="submit">Save</button>
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    </div>
}
</div>
```

I made a little view model too but...

```
 public class AddExtraViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

I apologise if this is all over the place but I did not write the original code. There were about 7 other programmers here before me and I'm just struggling to get through it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: on your controller code you don't show populating a model and sending it to the partial.  are you ending up with a blank partial?  What is the issue that you are trying to fix here?

Comment: Right now the issue I am trying to fix is how to get the stuff I fill into the popup window (which I can get) to be associated with the record I clicked. Lets say I click the first record and it has an ID of 21, I cant get this id in the popup. Also I cant get any other button working. There is a list of buttons but only the first one works because I hard coded the id. Because the way the grid is programmed, I cant figure out how to get the id passed to the popup so I can use it there, and save and assign my popup data to the record I clicked on.

Comment: I would like to thank those who took time to try to answer the question. However, I cant spend any more time trying to fix it as the boss has authorised me to remove all the junk and refactor / redesign it over the next day or two. However thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want something like this (using jQuery and jQuery UI):

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(int id) {
    return View(new YourModel { Id = id });
}
```

Partial View:

```
@model YourProject.Models.YourModel

// Partial view content e.g. the form etc.
```

Your view:

```
/<!-- html etc. -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" class="add-button" data-theId="@theModel.Id">Add</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".add-button").click(function(){
            var options = {
                autoOpen: false
            }
            var dialog = $("<div>").dialog(options);

            var id = $(this).data("theId");
            dialog.load("the/url/to/the/controller/action", { id: id }, function(){
                dialog.dialog("open");

                dialog.find("form").submit(function(){
                    // do stuff
                    dialog.remove();
                    return false;
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I know my sample code was not up by the time you answered. But would you help me a little more. In particular, the first piece of code that shows the main view with the table code is done partially with javascript and partially some other mess. I want to make the button ID as you have done, how can I do this with my code.

Comment: The code I refer to was.... new Helpers.GridColumn(value: (a) => "<input type=\"button\" class=\"btn\" id=\"BtnHello\" value=\"Add\" />"),   ......

Comment: That won't work because you are trying to get the model id in C#, where @ was meant as Razor syntax (in the view context, where you have access to the model)

Comment: What grid plugin are you using and how do you display it in your view?

Comment: There is a Grid.Column html helper which uses a bunch of strings to form the grid. These string are magic commands which are a combination of html/razor/c#/javascript. Then the "collection" of helpers are loaded into a html helper to build a table which has a bunch of other strings passed in to allow for filtering, sorting, totalling, and general configuration etc. Half of it in javascript, half C#. It outputs html at some point which uses bootstrap. The guys who build it are geniuses but obviously me as maintainer is not. But in saying this, I wouldn't want them building my rocket ship. :)

Comment: Looks like the column string is pre-defined so you cannot inject variables when you display the grid?

Comment: There is a pattern to the string alright...It takes a value as a lambda in the form (value: (a) => "<input... />"); The string after the => has to be valid html/css/javascript as it gets parsed into a bigger "string" (each defining more columns), which then gets parsed into more strings which then outputs and formats the html table. When I hover over it I see the type as "dynamic, dynamic".

Answer (score 0):

if you are building buttons in a forloop you don't want to define an id on the button.  Duplicate id's on a view can cause lots of issues.  Use a class on the buttons instead to trigger off of and use $(this) in your script to get details of the button that was clicked.  To access buttons on a partial or on items that are added to your page after page load you need to tie the click event for that button to the document like this

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnDetails", function(){
    //your script here
});
```

The other example uses "this" and shows how you can pass the id of the clicked button back to the controller.  The controller will need to be a little different though

```
public PartialViewResult PopulatePartial(int ID){
    var Model = //populate your model based on the passed id
    return PartialView("PartialViewName", Model);
}
```

Comment: Sounds good...I am having the same issue as with the other answer. It seems I cant give my buttons id's using razor syntax like id = '@model.recordID' as people normally would because of the way the code is built in the html. - see the first block of code where I have highlighted the problem. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I think I see what you are trying to accomplish.  the code you have posted should work for adding the id into the id field.  you say it doesn't work though.  What are you seeing instead?

Comment: With the code above - if I just do this simple code --->     $(".btn").click(function () { alert($(this).data("thisId")); });
<--- When I click on any button I get "undefined". If you can see what I am trying to accomplish...great! explain it to me please! just kidding. The code is really bad and I appreciate the help.